# Is there any work on partition a partial order set into minimum number total order subsets?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory, set-partition

The problem is what's the minimum number of total order subsets can a partial order set partition into?

For example, (1,2) and (3,4) are comparable i.e. (1,2) < (3,4), and (1,2) and (2,1) are incomparable. For the partial order set { (1,2), (3,4), (2,1)} we can partition into two subsets {(1,2), (3,4)} and {(2,1)}, which both are total order sets.

I searched on the web and found little related documents. The question is that whether any works or solutions on this problem exist?

Comment: Consider Dilworth's theorem.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Why not make that an answer?

Comment: @Arthur.  Too short.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Not at all.

Answer (score 4):

Given a finite partially ordered set, [Dilworth's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilworth%27s_theorem) says that the minimal number of totally ordered subsets needed to cover the entire set is equal to the size of the largest [antichain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antichain) (also known as the *width* of the set). An antichain is a subset where no element is comparable to any of the other elements in the antichain.